# Chart.js AJAX Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'data' of undefined

Tags: javascript, ajax, chart.js

I got some problems with ajax, I'm new to AJAX and im afraid that im doing alot of things stupid...

I want to create a Chart with Chart.js and make it dynamic for realtime.

So i got a db.php connects to my db, gets the necessary data and then encode the data to json. Then im trying to

```
$.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: 'db.php',
            contentType: "application/json",
            datatype: "JSON",                
            success: function(json) {
              var canvas = document.getElementById('id');
              var chart = Chart.Line(canvas, {
              data:chart.data
              });
              chart.data.labels = zeit;
              chart.data.datasets.data = json;
              chart.update();
              console.log(array);
            }});
```

actually this kind of thing works with global variables but not in the ajax function and i dont get why...
[error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9cJLR.png)

Any ideas?

Thank you :)

Comment: That error message is saying that `chart` is undefined because you are trying to access a variable in the middle of declaring it.  I would imagine that you would want to load the `data` from the `json` you are getting back from the AJAX request instead

Comment: @funador Thank you that works now!